# how to change css of n number of div element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to show 16 div in a format of 4x4 in case screen width is greater than `960px;`
and show 3x4 divs if screen width is `746px` and 2x6 in can width is `480px`

and 1x16 if screen width is `32px`;

i need to write a jquery where let us say if screen size is greater than `960px` then i need to remove border from last 4 divs.

I am not sure how to make it work example on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krGQc/42/

```
<div class="tdiv">1</div>
<div class="tdiv">2</div>
<div class="tdiv">3</div>
<div class="tdiv">4</div>
<div class="tdiv">5</div>
<div class="tdiv">6</div>
<div class="tdiv">7</div>
<div class="tdiv">8</div>
<div class="tdiv">9</div>
<div class="tdiv">10</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't media queries also work for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `gt()` with a negative index to count backwards from the last element.

```
if (window.screen.width > 960) { // you asked for "screen"
    $('.tdiv:gt(-5)').css('border','none');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/krGQc/44/)

Answer (score 1):

> using ***nth-last-child*** in css:

```
.tdiv:nth-last-child(-n+4)  {
    border:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b94Hg/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries in your CSS stylesheet:

```
.tdiv {
    /* Styling for width >= 960px */
}

@media all and (max-width: 746px) {

    .tdiv {
        /* Styling for width <= 746px */
    }

}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {

    .tdiv {
        /* Styling for width <= 480px */
    }

}
```

You can use the pseudo-class selectors [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) and [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-last-child) to hide the last n elements or remove the borders from it.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS media query

```
@media (min-width: 32px) and (max-width: 479px) { /* 1x16 */
    .tdiv {
        clear:left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 745px) { /* 2x6 */
    .tdiv:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear:left;
    }
    .tdiv:nth-child(n+13) {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 746px) and (max-width: 959px) { /* 3x4 */
    .tdiv:nth-child(3n+1) {
        clear:left;
    }
    .tdiv:nth-child(n+13) {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) { /* 4x4 */
    .tdiv:nth-child(4n+1) {
        clear:left;
    }
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/dBu27/)